# Not using all groups in ANOVA in R

Tags: r, anova

I am suppose to do an ANOVA in R an I have my data set something like this:

```
Sample   Protein1   Workout
  1         1.213      0
  2         2.653      -
  3         3.241      NA
  4         5.362      + 
  5         3.532      N
```

So there are 5 groups (NA, 0 , - , +, N) and when I do the ANOVA in R it dosn't use the NA group. But I also dont want to use the 0 group. Is there a way to do this or must I do a new dataset without the 0 group?

This is my code right now (I have 92 proteins):

```
x <- data.frame(p.value=sapply(df[,2:93], function(i) summary(aov(i ~ df$X.Workout))[[1]][["Pr(>F)"]][[1]]))
x[x$p.value < 0.05/92,,drop=F]
```

Also  noticed another problem when I wanted to change my data in my age column. In the column i have

```
25-35
35-45
45-55
25-35
35-45 
35-45
25-35
35-45
45-55
```

and so on. I want to change 35-45 and 45-55 to 35+ but when i write

```
df$X.Age[df$X.Age == "45-55"] <- "35+"
```

I get the following

```
In `[<-.factor`(`*tmp*`, df$X.Age == "45-55", value = c(1L, 1L,  :
  invalid factor level, NA generated
```

Comment: `NA` is treaded as a not available value by R, maybe you could just convert `NA` to a character string `NA`, that R will print as `<NA>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your data for 0 to NA if you also want to exclude it:

```
df$Workout[df$Workout == "0"] <- NA
```

or filter your data:

```
df <- df[df$Workout!=0, ]
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked. But notits another problem which I added.